# Repackage react components and import in a different environment

Tags: reactjs, npm

are there available libraries that can package react components and reuse it in a different application?

As of the moment, we can only import one component in a same application. What we want to do is to use that component in a different application.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with NPM?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to package your components as a library so that you can share them across different React apps? Or are you searching for a way to reuse React components inside non-React applications?

Comment: Already found a way to package it using npm pack